# Inability to detect the Output from inside a SSIS script component

Tags: ssis

In the script of the script components the Output buffer is not being detected as an existing component.

I am trying to use the following piece of code

Output0Buffer.AddRow();

within the  public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)

method. I know it should be available within this method because at the moment I am copying and using a component from a previous project that has this code and it works.

but when I create a new component and put the same code in it doesn't

Can any one explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you might verify that you set the SynchronousInputID to 0. It may have gotten changed when you copied the code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was stuck in the darkness and you gave me a flashlight...And batteries don't forget the batteries.